# Check if NFS is available from within Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, nfs, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile and the default option for mounting on non windows machines is NFS.

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows? == false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "core", :nfs => true,  :mount_options   => ['nolock,vers=3,udp']
end
```

However we have a developer that didn't have NFS installed on his 'nix box and it took awhile to figure out that was the problem.

Is there a way to check if the host machine has NFS installed in a similar approach from within the vagrantfile?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/host-capabilities.html The definition and implementation of host capabilities is identical to guest capabilities.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.   Those capabilities are for custom plugin development.  I was looking for something that I could use from within the Vagrant file.  Any other tips?

Comment: Maybe you can use the approach mentioned in http://superuser.com/questions/701735/run-script-on-host-machine-during-vagrant-up and have this script look if NFS is installed and install it if not.